# Inconsistencies error in storyboard with xcode 9.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, xcode9.2

[image]

I want to upgrade my application from Xcode 7.2 to Xcode 9.2 and swift version 4.1.

When I open storyboard below inconsistencies screen changes display.
I already added "OpenSans-Semibold" in my project target and plist file also.

Can anyone suggest how to resolve it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: check your Font is listed in target->Build Phase -> Copy Bundle Resources, if not than add your font file

Comment: @PratikPrajapati already added.

Comment: close Xcode. clean and build then try. if not working removed from project then drag n drop again. may resolve your problem

Comment: done still same

Comment: Open `Font Book` app in your mac, just search `Font Book`. Then click all font n add your font. then try again.

Comment: Thanks, it's working font not exist in Font book mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You just simple need to follow to steps.

1. Take the folder Fonts which you have added in your project
2. Open MAC Font Book and drag the Fonts folder in Font book.
3. Close the project -> Clean and Build

This will solve your error.
```